# can't get updated data in a pdf in php

Tags: php, sql, pdf, select

i am working on creating a pdf of my php form data. now when i update my form field i used to to redirect to direct on pdf , so user can download the updated data. but the problem is when i comes on a PDF page i did't get a updated data. i have to reload the page to get updated data.

so what can i do to get latest updated data on the pdf page.

This is the edit page code.

```
<?php

      error_reporting(0); 

      include 'dbconnect.php';

      $sql = "SELECT id, c_id, form_data FROM form WHERE id=".$_REQUEST['userid']."";


      $result = $conn->query($sql);

      if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {   

         $arrFinalFormData = json_decode($row["form_data"]);
         $row["form_data"] = str_replace("{", "", $row["form_data"]);
         $row["form_data"] = str_replace("}", "", $row["form_data"]);
         $arrFormData = explode(",", $row["form_data"]);
         $arrFormData2 = explode(":", $arrFormData[1]);
         $arrayName3 = array();

      }

      } else {
      echo "0 results";
      }

      $conn->close();
      ?>
```

the code to get data on the pdf page. is

```
         <?php
        include 'dbconnect.php'; 

        $sql = "SELECT id, form_data FROM form WHERE id=".$_REQUEST['userid']."";

        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

           while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {


              $arrFinalFormData = json_decode($row["form_data"]);



               $row["form_data"] = str_replace("{", "", $row["form_data"]);
               $row["form_data"] = str_replace("}", "", $row["form_data"]);

               $arrFormData = explode(",", $row["form_data"]);

               $arrFormData2 = explode(":", $arrFormData[1]);

               $arrayName3 = array();


           }

           mysql_free_result($result);

        } else {
           echo "0 results";
        }

        $conn->close();
        ?>
```

Comment: I guess your filename stays the same for each open? In which case pdf might get cached and not properly reloaded. Try adding a date-suffix in that case like stackoverflow-2016-01-02.pdf happy new year!

Comment: ok @jan i will work your suggestion ,,  & happy new Year to u also